# How to fetch tax rate in Magento?

Tags: magento

How can I fetch tax rate in Magento.

I have configure magneto so that shipping price is inclusive of tax. 
Tax rule is separately defined for each country
I have 4 stores.

Now, I want tax rule for Store #1. How can I get

Krish

Comment: $FlatRate = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::FLAT_RATE, $this->getStore());
Mage::helper('tax')->getShippingPrice($shipping)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Elisha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633650/krishna-sunuwar) (OP) already self-answered the question.

Quote:

```
$FlatRate = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::FLAT_RATE, $this->getStore());
Mage::helper('tax')->getShippingPrice($shipping)
```

<sub>Note: It's absolutely [OK to self-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519) your own question. Please just post it as an real answer, but *not* in a question or comment. Posting as real answer helps to keep the "Unanswered" list more clear (avoids making other people wasting their time).</sub>